# creating custom drawing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Here is my code:

```
$('#add_shape').click(function() {
    var rectHeight = $('#rect_height_input').val();
    var rectWidth = $('#width_input').val();

    $('<canvas>').attr({
        id: 'canvas'
    }).css({
        height: function() {
            if (rectHeight > 0) {
                return rectHeight + 'px';
            }
            else {
                return rectWidth + 'px';
            }
        },
        width: rectWidth + 'px'
    }).appendTo('#work_area');

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillStyle = $('#color_list option:selected').val();
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
});
```

When the `#add_shape` button is clicked, the rectangle does not show up. What am I missing here? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In response to previous [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8514358/2):**

You retrieved existing canvas element using `document.getElementById()` and then you created another one using jQuery `$('<canvas>')` and appended it to `#work_area`.

Change `$('<canvas>')` into `$(canvas)` to use the already existing canvas.

Did you really want to call `document.getElementById('canvas')` instead of `document.createElement('canvas')`? In the 1st case there must be already a canvas element in the DOM with the `id="canvas"` which looks suspicious.

**Edit #1 (in response to current revision):**

If that was just a wrote code in the answer then check your HTML (which you should also provide). Your code is working as demonstrated in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/xwg5f/)**.

Make sure that IDs are correct - You are using `#rect_height_input` for height, but `#width_input` for width and double-check values for the color options - maybe the rectangle is drawin using white color.

**Edit #2 (in response to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/) in comments):**

- For each shape you create a new canvas element and all those elements have same (!) id. This is incorrect. Attribute `id` of an element should be unique. In your code you will always get the first canvas and draw on it - now matter how many shapes you crated. Rest of canvas elements are empty.
- Your code is drawing rectangles correctly (apart from the "same canvas" problem). Try to draw rectangle with big height and width - it is working. When the width/height are very small then the canvas is too small to show the rectangle. Setting minimum width/height or using one big canvas and drawing shapes onto it is a way to go.

Comment: @dzejkej--i meant to put the `getElementById('canvas')` and the other canvas methods AFTER the creation of the canvas. My edits have been made.

That being said, can you think of anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: @codeninja See update of my answer. If the issue is solved then it would be great if you can let us know where the problem was and appreciate our time spent on it (and the previous revision) :P. If it is still not running even after you had a look on the fiddle, then show the HTML code :).

Comment: @dzejkej--here is a fiddle of my work so far: http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/

My questions deal with the 'Add Shape' button on the left. So far code has only been attached for rectangles. 

Ad you can see my class names are different than your example, but everything in the document is internally consistent. Can you find anything wrong?

Comment: @dzejkej--youre right, the canvas is being created, but for some reason the *color* is not being applied. First i thought it was a `zIndex` issue, but even when set to 25, the canvas is still not 'appearing' (colorwise). Any thoughts?

Comment: @codeninja I use Chrome and the rectangle has proper color. Use for example with = 150, height = 150. The only problem I have there is the fillRect call which is drawing not the exact rectangle it should. Also I'm updating the answer ... I think we should close this question - the Q you asked is answered and solution to it is working. Create a new question with your current code and let everybody answer. Nobody is reading these comments and it would be a good idea if somebody else had a chance to see it and spot all the problems.

Comment: @dzejkej--haha thanks for working on it for so long. i really dont know whats going on, the canvases arent appearing on my browser even with height and width set to 300px. the `fillRect()` method automatically fills shapes right? even with a separate `ctx.fill()` the shapes are not showing up...

Comment: @codeninja Please "finish" this question by accepting/upvoting/whatever :) then fix the id problem, create a new question where you insert the `$('#add_shape').click` JavaScript snippet, provides a link to the fiddle, write guide how to reproduce the problem (add rectangles) and don't forget to mention what browser are you using. More people can help and I swear I will have a look :P.

Comment: @dzejkej--here is the new fiddle, class problem corrected. I've added a conditional to deal with the shape choice, and the shapes are still not appearing. http://jsfiddle.net/RymyY/5/

I'm not allowed to ask anymore questions today o_o. i feel like this is a simple problem, i just cant see what the solution is

Comment: @codeninja It is not fixed. You are assigning id `#x1`, but you are asking for id `canvas` which is not found. Also change `id:'#' + thisCanvas` to `id: thisCanvas`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5887/discussion-between-dzejkej-and-codeninja)